# Unity IronSource build errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, ironsource

I have implemented IronSource SDK to my game project. Whenever I try it on any of my project, I got the namespace error that I have mentioned above.[Global namespace error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnKLL.png)
This is awkward because the script that I am getting error from is IronSource's own scripts. I have not changed any of them. Another weird point is that I am getting this error in each of my project whether it is newly created or not. But that is not my main problem, I can solve it by giving it its own namespace. This is what ChatGPT said to me.

Now, I am getting assembly errors. I have never faced with this problem when I was trying to implement IronSource.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw0Ub.png)

I have implemented this SDK to an earlier version of my game which is basically a git clone. My project is on both unity dashboard and IronSource. I do not know if it causes any problem.

Edit:

-> I have searched my assets and can not find any scripts that is related with IronSource instead of my downloads. As far as I know, adding it is just dragging into assets and importing everything. Deleting this is basically removing its folder. I do not know if there can be any file that makes this error occur.

-> I have downloaded it from its official manual. I used both newer version and its prior. Nothing has changed, I got the same error every time.

Comment: Can you say where you download ironSource plugin?

Comment: I imported IronSource plugin from their official manual and don't meet this error. https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/unity/unity-plugin/#step-1 I bet you have own IronSource class in your project and don't use namespaces and asmdefs. Or maybe you somehow imported IronSource twice or something.

Comment: Please post error codes as text and not as an image. It makes life easier for your helpers.